# Route Doesn't Exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, routes

I'm in Rails 4. I'm using the rails-api gem. My controllers are in controllers/api/v1/. The one I'm currently using is patients_controller.rb.

My routes look like:

```
namespace :api, :constraints => {:subdomain => "api"}, :defaults => {:format => :json} do
  namespace :v1 do
    match "patient/:id", to: "patient#show", via: :get
    match "recording/:id", to: "recording#delete", via: :delete
  end
end
```

When I run rake routes I get:

```
api_v1 GET    /api/v1/patient/:id(.:format)   api/v1/patient#show {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
DELETE /api/v1/recording/:id(.:format) api/v1/recording#delete {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
```

But when I got from local host /api/v1/patient/2.json I get the following error from the server:

```
Started GET "/api/v1/patient/2.json" 
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/api/v1/patient/2.json")
```

I've restarted the server. I've restarted the terminal. What am I missing?

Comment: It looks like the subdomain constraint is the cause of the problem.  Remove that for testing.  Ultimately, you'd need to setup that hostname in your dev server and use that name to test these routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add local too to your subdomain

```
namespace :api, :constraints => {:subdomain => /^(?!www|api|local)(\w+)/}, :defaults => {:format => :json} do
  namespace :v1 do
    match "patient/:id", to: "patient#show", via: :get
    match "recording/:id", to: "recording#delete", via: :delete
  end
end
```